# Converting String to Time Format returns nil Data

Tags: ios, objective-c

My Json is

```
{
 "MinPerAppointment": "30",
 "OpeningTime": "12:05"    
}
```

Now, I want to Add 30 to 12:05, which Should be 12:35, I could not get How to format it, SO, I tried it with NSdate

```
NSString *str_MinPerAppointment = timeDetailData.minPerAppointment;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str_MinPerAppointment];

NSString *dateInString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];    
NSLog(@"New AppointMentValue :%@",dateInString);
```

I am getting New AppointMentValue as **nil**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `NSDate` formatting.  Simply convert `HH:MM` to minutes (or seconds, if you deal with them), do your math and then convert back.

Something like:

```
NSString *time = @"12:30";
int addMinutes = 30;
int hh, mm;
if (sscanf([time UTF8String], "%d:%d", &hh, &mm) == 2) {
    int minutes = (hh * 60) + mm;
    minutes += addMinutes;
    hh = minutes / 60;
    mm = minutes - (hh * 60);
    hh %= 24;    // day roll-over
    NSString *newTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02:%02d", hh, mm];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid time value: %@", time);
}
```

Comment: @Droppy: What a awesome logic!! But I don't understand the sscanf?

Comment: @Droppy how to compare value like 12:35 >= 20:30 in string way, Update me

Comment: @SaurabhJain It's a legacy C function for parsing strings.  There are better Objective-C ways of doing it.

Comment: @Imran Then you need to keep the time in minutes internally (i.e. don't convert back to string).

Comment: @Droppy i ahve updated my quest. please update ur answer

Comment: @Droppy i understand ur point. i missed some point in my question so i updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117181/discussion-between-imran-and-droppy).

Comment: @Imran You can use the same approach as shown in my answer.  Convert all input times into minutes, generate your range of appointment slots and convert each slot from minutes -> hh:mm and add to array.  Pretty simple and way better than the poor answer you accepted over there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `NSDateFormatter/NSDate` try this-

```
NSString *str_MinPerAppointment = @"30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12:05"] ;

NSString *dateInString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[myDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*[str_MinPerAppointment integerValue]]];

NSLog(@"New AppointMentValue :%@",dateInString);
```

Comment: `NSDate` without specifying the `year` can cause unexpected behavior.