# How to get Time between 2 String values which are in String form

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Have Shop Working Hour JSON

```
{
  "MinPerAppointment": "30",
  "OpeningTime": "10:30",
  "BreakStartTime": "12:00",
  "BreakEndTime": "13:00",
  "ClosingTime": "19:30"
 }
```

I want to get All Data of time Interval of 30(MinPerAppointment) **OpeningTime** to **ClosingTime** by **Neglecting BreakStartTime and BreakEndTime**.

I want to get in Data in this Format

10:30

11:00

11:30

..Neglected Data Between BreakStartTime to BreakEndTime.. , which is 12 to 13:00

13:00

13:30

.....

.....

19:00

Comment: You are in India? With a difference of +5:30? The difference should be the same.

Comment: I am getting 2000-01-01 05:30:00 +0000 but i have set it 'HH:mm'.

Comment: 5:30 (date you get) + 5:30 (India Time) gives 11:00 at India Time. So there is no issue. If your issue is about 200-01-01, it's because you didn't specify a year/month/day. Plus a+c - (b+c) = a-b.

Comment: @Larme i want to get Data between time Interval of 30(MinPerAppointment) New_AppointMentValue to ClosingTime by Neglecting BreakStartTime and BreakEndTime. for this what i have to to do

Comment: can you post as an example what final value you want at the end? So that it clear to understand for all user..

Comment: @Dev.RK sure i will update my post

Comment: @Dev.RK now check my updated quest

Comment: @Imran please check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this-

```
NSString *dateInString=@"11:15";// your OpeningTime

NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *str_MinPerAppointment = @"30"; // your MinPerAppointment

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *Breaktime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"14:00"] ; // your breakStartTime

NSDate *BreaktimeEnd = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15:00"] ; // your breakEndTime

NSDate *closeTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20:30"] ; // your closeTime

while ([[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateInString] compare:closeTime] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateInString] ;

    if([myDate compare:Breaktime] == NSOrderedDescending && [myDate compare:BreaktimeEnd] == NSOrderedAscending){

    }else{
        if ([myDate compare:Breaktime]==NSOrderedSame) {

        }else{
            [array addObject:dateInString];
        }
    }

    dateInString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[myDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*[str_MinPerAppointment integerValue]]];

}

NSLog(@"your data :%@",array);
```

OP:-

```
your data :(
"10:30",
"11:00",
"11:30",
"13:00",
"13:30",
"14:00",
"14:30",
"15:00",
"15:30",
"16:00",
"16:30",
"17:00",
"17:30",
"18:00",
"18:30",
"19:00"
)
```

Comment: it works bro.. but last i m getting 19:30 i have to show values before MinPerAppointment , which s 30 in my case so i have to show values before 19:00. last value should based on MinPerAppointment

Comment: means you don't want 19:30?

Comment: i can remove last object is array bro but i dont want to do that

Comment: if you don't want 19:30 in array, then just move [array addObject:dateInString]; above myDate in else condition..

Comment: @Imran Happy to help you bro:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117211/discussion-between-imran-and-dev-rk).

Answer (score 1):

As per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38346276/3588973) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38346155/3588973), I would take the following approach.  You do not want to be comparing strings for time data:

1. Convert all string hh:mm times into integer minutes.
2. Iterate from the opening time to the closing time (minus appointment slot time) in steps of appointment slot time.
3. If the time is between break start and end then ignore.
4. Convert each value to an hh:mm string and add it to an array.

   ```
   + (int)minutesFromHhmm:(NSString *)hhmm
   {
       int minutes = 0, hh, mm;
       if (sscanf([hhmm UTF8String], "%d:%d", &hh, &mm) == 2)
           minutes = (hh * 60) + mm;
       return minutes;
   }

   + (NSString *)hhmmFromMinutes:(int)minutes
   {
       int hh = minutes / 60;
       int mm = minutes - (hh * 60);
       hh %= 24;    // day roll-over
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02:%02d", hh, mm];
   }

   - (NSMutableArray *)yourMethod:(NSDictionary *)jsonData
   {
       // 1.
       int minAppointmentTime = [self minutesFromHhmm:jsonData[@"MinPerAppointment"]];
       int openingTime = [self minutesFromHhmm:jsonData[@"OpeningTime"]];
       int breakStartTime = [self minutesFromHhmm:jsonData[@"BreakStartTime"]];
       int breakEndTime = [self minutesFromHhmm:jsonData[@"BreakEndTime"]];
       int closingTime = [self minutesFromHhmm:jsonData[@"ClosingTime"];

       NSMutableArray *appointmentSlots = [NSMutableArray new];

       // 2.
       for (int time = openingTime; time <= closingTime - minAppointmentTime; time += minAppointmentTime) {
           if (time >= breakStartTime && time <= breakEndTime)
               continue;      // 3.
           [appointmentSlots addObject:[self hhmmFromMinutes:time]];   // 4.
       }

       return appointmentSlots;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate * dt1 ;

    NSDate * dt2 ;

    dt1 = [df dateFromString: txt1.text];
    dt2 = [df dateFromString: txt2.text];

    NSComparisonResult result = [dt1 compare: dt2];

    switch (result) {
        case NSOrderedAscending:
            NSLog(@"%@ is greater than %@", dt2, dt1);
            break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:
            NSLog(@"%@ is less %@", dt2, dt1);
            break;
        case NSOrderedSame:
            NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@", dt2, dt1);
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", dt2, dt1);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: are u still facing issue

Comment: The dateFormat and the string doesn't match. `dt1` and `dt2` should be both nil.

Comment: @Cyph3r i m getting (null) is equal to (null)
by ur code. please check it

Comment: @Larme how can i frame condition between 2 time string to get all values on particular interval( in my case 30)